# How to write a Countifs formula in Excel?

Tags: excel

When I drag or copy the formula to another cell then the date should be changed. Every time I need to change the date manually.

Only date should change when I drag the formula as this is a monthly.

Example is given below.

```
=COUNTIFS($M$35:$M$1007,”=1/9/2018″,$N$35:$N$1007,”TS”,$O$35:$O$1007,”HP”,$P$35:$P$1007,”1″)
=COUNTIFS($M$35:$M$1007,”=2/9/2018″,$N$35:$N$1007,”TS”,$O$35:$O$1007,”HP”,$P$35:$P$1007,”1″)
=COUNTIFS($M$35:$M$1007,”=3/9/2018″,$N$35:$N$1007,”TS”,$O$35:$O$1007,”HP”,$P$35:$P$1007,”1″)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the DATE function to return a true date. The DATEVALUE function is an alternative but I prefer DATE. Don't quote numbers. Try not to use ambiguous DMY/MDY dates for examples. You don't need equals (e.g. `=`) signs in a COUNTIFS.

Quoted strings do not change when dragged or copied to a new location. You need to include something that changes.

I've assumed a DMY date system. For 01-Sep-2018,

```
=COUNTIFS($M$35:$M$1007, date(2018, 9, row(1:1)), $N$35:$N$1007, "TS", $O$35:$O$1007, "HP", $P$35:$P$1007, 1)
```

Fill down for 02-Sep-2018, 03-Sep-2018, etc.

Alternative for dragging across.

```
=COUNTIFS($M$35:$M$1007, date(2018, 9, column(a:a)), $N$35:$N$1007, "TS", $O$35:$O$1007, "HP", $P$35:$P$1007, 1)
```

Be careful about putting 'smart quote' in your formulas. Your examples were littered with them and they don't work in formulas.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to define the dates you care about in their own column, and then make sure that the reference to them is unlocked within the formula:

```
 'A'         'B'
|date_field| formula                                                 |
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------
| 1/9/2018 |=COUNTIFS($M$35:$M$1007,$A1,$N$35:$N$1007,"TS", ... etc) |
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------
| 2/9/2018 |=COUNTIFS($M$35:$M$1007,$A2,$N$35:$N$1007,"TS", ... etc) |
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------
| 3/9/2018 |=COUNTIFS($M$35:$M$1007,$A3,$N$35:$N$1007,"TS", ... etc) |
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------
```